# varnishncsa not logging custom headers

Tags: varnish

I'm using Varnish 3.0.2 on a Debian Wheezy system.  I'd like to be able to set custom headers and have their contents appear in the request logs.  However, although I know the headers are being set and passed to the back end, their contents don't seem to be visible to `varnishncsa`.

In my `vcl_recv` I have

```
set req.http.X-my-header = "blahblah";
```

and, for testing, this is my custom format string for `varnishncsa`:

```
'%{X-my-header}i'
```

I should see `blahblah` in the log for each request.  However, all I get is `-`.  It seems that my header isn't being passed through to `varnishncsa`.

How can I include my custom headers in my logs?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue and this was the top result when searching for it, so I'll post my solution/workaround here for future reference :)

`varnishncsa` can log values set by `std.log("key:value")` in VCL [1](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/varnishncsa.html). I used this to log my custom header. Using your example, add this in your `vcl_recv`:

```
set req.http.X-my-header = "blahblah";
std.log("X-my-header:" + req.http.X-my-header);
```

Then use the following somewhere in your logformat string for `varnishncsa` (mind the x in stead of the i after the header name):

```
%{VCL_Log:X-my-header}x
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a bug in Varnish Book when it comes to explaining how to log headers. Try this:

```
varnishncsa -F '<%{age}o> <%{x-cache}o> %U %s'
```